# Multiple-choice quiz in Moodle

Tags: moodle

First off, I am a beginner. I am trying to write a multiple choice quiz in which there can be more than one answer. Each item is worth 0.5 points and the total score should be 2 points.
For example:

Which numbers are prime?
a) 5
b) 6 
c) 7
d) 8

Thus the student that chooses only a) and c) gets 2 points; the student that chooses only a) (or only c)) will get 1.5 points; etc.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a multiple choice question.

Then select "multiple answers are allowed" in the settings.

Then you can weight the answers.

See https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Multiple_Choice_question_type